# plotting boolean variable as geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, boolean

I am fairly new to R and ggplotting. I'm trying to line plot the total of TRUE observations across time, but the counts seem to be capped at 1.00.

```
dd <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3), 
                 y = c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE))

ggplot(dd,aes(x,as.numeric(y)))+
  geom_line()
```

[image: result of the plot]

count(as.numeric(y)) does not work, can you help me?

Comment: Try with `ggplot(count(dd, x, wt = y), aes(x, n))+ geom_line()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to prepare the statistics before graphing them

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# summarized the TRUE count for each x value
graph_data <- dd %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(count_y = sum(y))

# plot the data using geom_line
ggplot(data = graph_data) +
  geom_line(aes(x, count_y)) +
  # added the scale y for start the y-axis from 0
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA), expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>